# ¿No puedo insertar en la tabla usuario desde mi app o via pagina web, resultado= false? pero desde phpmyadmin SQL si inserta

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, log

Estoy alquilando un servidor virtual **(VPS)**, desde que lo alquile y subi mis archivos estoy teniendo muchos problemas con su version php con la que viene el servidor **(PHP 7.2)**, puedo hacer inserciones y consultas a otras tablas de la BD, pero en usuario es donde mas se concentra mas el problema, en mi **localhost** de mi **pc** y en un **hosting compartido premium** de **hostinger** funciona perfectamente, al principio me molestaba el datetime que no recibia **zero** en fechas **"0000-00-00 00:00:00"** pero ya lo ajuste, pero es otra cosa que me impide registrar en la tablas usuario y no se que sera, se que es la version de **php 7.2** que me esta impidiendo insertar y es algo que no veo. En apache2 y mysql en el archivo **error.log** del VPS no arroja ningun error.

**Dejare anexos:**

**Tabla usuario y sus estructuras de datos:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi archivo php llamado desde una funcion ajax:**

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('conexion.php');
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

sleep(2);

$txtIdentificacion = "1065906453";
$txtCorreo = "gayaquiver18@gmail.com";
$txtNombreusuario = "Gaya2022";
$txtContraseña = "1234";

$hash = md5(rand(0,1000));
$secret = md5($txtContraseña);
$query = "INSERT INTO usuario (identificacion, nombre, contraseña, correo, hash, ultima_sesion) VALUES (
'$txtIdentificacion','$txtNombreusuario','$secret','$txtCorreo','$hash','0000-00-00 00:00:00')";
   
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

print json_encode($resultado);
$conexion = null;
```

**Funcion ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://**************************/registrar_usuario.php",
            data: {Identificacion: txtIdentificacion, Correo: txtCorreo, Nombreusuario: txtNombreusuario, Contraseña: txtContraseña},
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                
                $("#contenidoesconder").hide();
                $("#imgCargando").show();
                $("#imgCargando").css({"display": "block", "margin": "110px auto", "max-width": "100%", "width": "30%"});
                $("#mensaje4").show();
                $("#mensaje4").css({"display": "block", "margin": "110px auto", "max-width": "100%", "width": "30%"});
            },
            success: function(data){

                console.log(data);
```

Comment: En lugar de fecha en ceros, intenta usar `NULL` y, de paso, lee la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) para saber las directivas que debes modificar en caso de querer usar ese formato.

Comment: nada, no funciono con NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estamos ante otro caso de lo que yo llamo *programación optimista*, es decir, escribir código pensando en que vivimos en un mundo color de rosa donde todo funcionará según lo esperado.

No siempre es así, pueden ocurrir errores y una parte importante de tu tarea como programador es **prever esos errores y afrontarlos**, yo llamo a eso *programación pesimista*.

Veamos un ejemplo de programa robusto, donde prevés los posibles errores, controlas el flujo e informas adecuadamente al usuario de lo que haya ocurrido.

De paso, te aconsejo que evites el uso de `ñ` y de acentos en nombres de variables y de tablas o columnas. Cualquier problema en la codificación romperá tu programa. Dado que manejaras datos en español, deberías prever eso también con respecto a la conexión. Dado que no sé si usas mysqli o PDO, no pondré configuración de charset en la conexión, pero es algo que deberías hacer.

#### PHP

```
  <?php
  include('conexion.php');
  $objeto = new Conexion();
  $conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
  /*
    1er error posible: la conexión no funciona 
  */
  if ($conexion) {

    # ¿Para qué es esto?
    sleep(2);

    /*
      Supongo que te interesa recuperar los datos 
      que has pasado por POST ...
      aquí los recogemos con operador de fusión de null 
    */

    # ¿La columna identificación no es autoincrement????
    $id = $_POST['Identificacion'] ?? null;
    $userName = $_POST['Nombreusuario'] ?? null;
    $password = $_POST['Password'] ?? null;
    $hash = md5(rand(0,1000));
    $secret = md5($txtPassword);
    $mail = $_POST['Correo'] ?? null; 

    /*
      2º error posible: 
      debes verificar todas las columnas de la tabla 
      que no admitan valores nulos 
    */
    if ($id && $userName && $password && $hash && $mail){
      /*
        Aquí deberías usar consultas preparadas 
      */
      $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (identificacion, nombre, contraseña, correo, hash, ultima_sesion) VALUES ($id, '$userName', '$secret', '$mail', '$hash', null)";

      /*
          3er error posible: la consulta falla 
      */
      if ($resultado = $conexion->query($query)) {
        $outPut=array(
                        'status'=>true, 
                        'msg'=>sprintf('Filas insertadas: %d',$conexion->affected_rows)
                      );  
      } else {
        $outPut=array(
                        'status'=>false, 
                        'msg'=>sprintf('Error insertando: %s',$conexion->error)
                      );  
      }
    } else {
      $outPut=array(
                      'status'=>false, 
                      'msg'=>'Algunos datos son nulos'
                    );
    }
  } else {
    $outPut=array(
                    'status'=>false, 
                    'msg'=>'No hay conexión'
                  );
  }

  $conexion = null;
  header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($outPut);
```

#### Javascript

NÓTESE que en el servidor se ha aplicado el siguiente *contrato*: **cuando haya algún fallo, la respuesta tendrá una clave `status` con valor `false`, de lo contrario tendrá un valor `true` y en ambos casos tendrá una clave `msg` con un mensaje de lo que haya ocurrido.

Ahora, aplicaremos eso al recibir la respuesta en el cliente:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://**************************/registrar_usuario.php",
            data: {Identificacion: txtIdentificacion, Correo: txtCorreo, Nombreusuario: txtNombreusuario, Password: txtContraseña},
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                
                $("#contenidoesconder").hide();
                $("#imgCargando").show();
                $("#imgCargando").css({"display": "block", "margin": "110px auto", "max-width": "100%", "width": "30%"});
                $("#mensaje4").show();
                $("#mensaje4").css({"display": "block", "margin": "110px auto", "max-width": "100%", "width": "30%"});
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status) {
                    //La inserción se realizó
                } else {
                    //Ocurrió algún error
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
                //Resto de tu código
```

Comment: Hola, ya pase tu codigo a mi codigo, donde aparece ese msg en php, para ver en que if entro la condicion.

Comment: @Gayaquiver no entendí tu comentario. ¿Cuál es el mensaje que muestra ahora?

Comment: Listo, eres un crack, el problema era mas por las ñ, no tuve que quitarlas, especifique todo lo que decia en este link sobre los problemas sobre los acentos y ñ: https://www.oscarperez.es/problemas-con-las-enes-acentos-y-demas-caracteres-cuando-usas-mysql-y-php/

Comment: https://www.oscarperez.es/problemas-con-las-enes-acentos-y-demas-caracteres-cuando-usas-mysql-y-php/

Comment: Gracias crack!!!

Answer (score 0):

Además del tema con la fecha (que podrías pasar NULL como valor o directamente no incluir ese campo en la consulta ya que NULL es el valor por defecto) lo que veo raro es que el campo `identificacion` lo estés tomando desde afuera en lugar de declararlo como autoincremental en la tabla. Me da la impresión que la consulta falla por querer guardar una clave primaria duplicada.

Comment: ya intente quitando la ultima sesion y no dio resultado, i la identificacion es unica de cada usuario que se conectara con otra base de datos del gobierno, BD relacionales.